# Match a value with an XML et un CSV et change it

Tags: php, arrays, xml, csv

I need to change a value in a XML (is a value of a price). I get this XML in the same repository of my file PHP.

For do that, i have 1 file XML where there is the value that i want change (there are multiple products), and a .CSV with three columns (this CSV also is in the same repository of the index.php):

- Column A and Column B rapresent a range of weight
- Column C is the price that i want take for change the value in XML.

Example:

```
    XML
    <weight>2.5</weight>
    <price>5</price>

    CSV
    | COLUMN A| COLUMN B| COLUMN C|

    |:---- |:------:| -----:|

    | 2     | 3     | 5      |
```

So in that case i need to add 5 from column C in the value of XML "price".

Now, i need to convert the XML (but also the CSV ) in a multidimensional array like that:

```
[1] 
     COLUMN A => 1
     COLUMN B => 2
     COLUMN C => 5
[2]  
     COLUMN A => 2
     COLUMN B => 3
     COLUMN C => 10
  ...
```

The idea is doin a loop in the XML multidimensional array and a second loop in the CSV array and get the COLUMN C if the weight is beetween COLUMN A and COLUMN B.

The problem is that i son't know how convert the XML and the CSV into the array with KEY (COLUMN A) => VALUE (1).

I used simplexml_load_file for the XML and fgetcsv  for the CSV, but is not what i need.

Can you help me on doing that  Thank you !

That s my code:

```
<?php
function getXmlToArray (string $xmlName) {
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($xmlName) or die("<br/>Errore di caricamento<br/>");
    return $xml;
}

function getDeliveryPrice(){
    $csv = 'prezzi_spedizione_francia.csv';
    $file = fopen($csv, 'r');

    while (!feof($file) ) {
        $arrayCsv[] = fgetcsv($file, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $arrayCsv;
    

}


$xml = getXmlToArray("pre-FR_1.xml");
$listaPrezzi = getDeliveryPrice();
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <sku>35</sku>
    <sku_manufacturer>FIN 260182300000</sku_manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Finder</manufacturer>
    <ean>8012823238074</ean>
    <title><![CDATA[Finder interrupteur à impulsion relais 230v 26018230]]></title>
    <description><![CDATA[<p>Finder 230v relais <span>électromécanique à impulsion avec circuit bobine et contacts séparés avec 1 contact NO</span>.</p><p><strong>Caractéristiques :</strong></p>
<ul><li>Nombre de contacts 1NO</li>
<li>Courant nominal/ Courant instantané max. 10/20A</li>
<li>Tension nominale/Tension maximale de commutation 250/400 VAC</li>
<li>Charge nominale en AC1 2500VA</li>
<li>Charge nominale en AC15 (230 V AC) 500VA</li>
<li>Charge de commutation minimale 1000 (10/10) mW (V/mA)</li>
<li>Matériau de contact standard AgNi</li>
<li>Tension d'alimentation nominale (UN) 230 V AC (50 Hz)</li>
<li>Isolation entre la bobine et les contacts (1,2/50 μs) 4 kV</li>
<li>Température ambiante -40...+40 degrés</li>
<li>Degré de protection IP20</li>
</ul><p><strong>Capacité de la lampe</strong></p>
<ul><li>Incandescent/halogène 230 V 800 W</li>
<li>Fluorescents avec ballast électronique 400W</li>
<li>Fluorescents avec ballast électromagnétique déphasé 360W</li>
<li>CFL 200W</li>
<li>LED 230 V 200W</li>
<li>Halogène ou BT LED avec transformateur électronique 200W</li>
<li>Halogène ou LED BT avec transformateur électromagnétique de 400W</li>
</ul><p></p><ul><li><b>Typologie </b> : Relais</li><li><b>Type</b> : Interrupteur</li><li><b>Installation</b> : Encastré</li></ul>]]></description>
    <product_price_vat_inc>10.08</product_price_vat_inc>
    <shipping_price_vat_inc>0</shipping_price_vat_inc>
    <quantity>3233</quantity>
    <brand><![CDATA[Finder]]></brand>
    <merchant_category><![CDATA[Accueil/Automatisation/Automatisation domestique]]></merchant_category>
    <product_url><![CDATA[https://www.elettronew.com/fr/automatisation-domestique/finder-interrupteur-a-impulsion-relais-230v-26018230-35.html]]></product_url>
    <image_1><![CDATA[https://www.elettronew.com/35872/finder-interrupteur-a-impulsion-relais-230v-26018230.jpg]]></image_1>
    <image_2><![CDATA[]]></image_2>
    <image_3><![CDATA[]]></image_3>
    <image_4><![CDATA[]]></image_4>
    <image_5><![CDATA[]]></image_5>
    <retail_price_vat_inc/>
    <product_vat_rate>22</product_vat_rate>
    <shipping_vat_rate>20</shipping_vat_rate>
    <manufacturer_pdf/>
    <ParentSKU/>
    <parent_title/>
    <Cross_Sell_Sku/>
    <ManufacturerWarrantyTime/>
    <use_grid>1</use_grid>
    <carrier>Courrier DHL Standard (FR)</carrier>
    <shipping_time>2#4</shipping_time>
    <carrier_grid_1>Courrier DHL Standard (FR)</carrier_grid_1>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_1>2#5</shipping_time_carrier_grid_1>
    <carrier_grid_2/>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_2/>
    <carrier_grid_3/>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_3/>
    <carrier_grid_4/>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_4/>
    <carrier_grid_5/>
    <shipping_time_carrier_grid_5/>
    <DisplayWeight>0.050000</DisplayWeight>
    <free_return/>
    <min_quantity>1</min_quantity>
    <increment>1</increment>
    <sales>0</sales>
    <eco_participation>0</eco_participation>
    <shipping_price_supplement_vat_inc>0</shipping_price_supplement_vat_inc>
    <Unit_count>-1.000000</Unit_count>
    <Unit_count_type/>
  </Product>

CSV
COLUMN A;COLUMN B;COLUMN C
0;1;14,5
1;2;20
2;3;21
3;4;22
4;5;23
5;6;23,5
6;7;23,5
7;8;25
8;9;26
9;10;27
```

Comment: Do both files contain the exact same number of products and does each product (in both files) contain exactly the same 3 pieces of information? Are the products in the same order in both files and are all prices to be replaced? Please provide a better dataset for both files

Comment: no. In the XML i have a lot of KEY. But just the KEY "weight" i have to get for search the correct prince in the CSV (that contain just 3 columns).  So in the XML i have the weight and in the CSV the range of weight (From A to B) for get the price (C)

Comment: please provide proper samples of the actual data and not the little pieces shown above. It is very difficult to visualise what the data is and what you are trying to do ~ it might make more sense if we can see actual xml and csv data as it is

Comment: i provide to add this at the end of question

Comment: I can not see either `weight` or `price` within that XML sample

Comment: weight =  <DisplayWeight>
price =  <product_price_vat_inc>

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I have understood correctly that you wish to update the XML file ( specifically the `shipping_price_vat_inc` node value ) if the weight ( `DisplayWeight` ) value lies between the low & high values found within the CSV file.

Ignoring `SimpleXML` ( never used it ) and instead using `DOMDocument`, `DOMXPath` and `SplFileObject` with the following source files.

**xmlsource.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <sku>35</sku>
    <sku_manufacturer>FIN 260182300000</sku_manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Finder</manufacturer>
    <ean>8012823238074</ean>
    <product_price_vat_inc>10.08</product_price_vat_inc>
    <quantity>3233</quantity>
    <!-- weight & price -->
    <shipping_price_vat_inc>0</shipping_price_vat_inc>
    <DisplayWeight>0.050000</DisplayWeight>
    <!-- -->
    <Unit_count>-1.000000</Unit_count>
    <Unit_count_type/>
  </Product>
  
  <Product>
    <sku>36</sku>
    <sku_manufacturer>FIN 260752300870</sku_manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Finder</manufacturer>
    <ean>803453238074</ean>
    <product_price_vat_inc>13.68</product_price_vat_inc>
    <quantity>7833</quantity>
    <!-- weight & price -->
    <shipping_price_vat_inc>0</shipping_price_vat_inc>
    <DisplayWeight>5.0850000</DisplayWeight>
    <!-- -->
    <Unit_count>-1.000000</Unit_count>
    <Unit_count_type/>
  </Product>
  
  <Product>
    <sku>37</sku>
    <sku_manufacturer>FIN 2601978970000</sku_manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Finder</manufacturer>
    <ean>80128234674374</ean>
    <product_price_vat_inc>199.44</product_price_vat_inc>
    <quantity>32543</quantity>
    <!-- weight & price -->
    <shipping_price_vat_inc>0</shipping_price_vat_inc>
    <DisplayWeight>6.0650000</DisplayWeight>
    <!-- -->
    <Unit_count>-1.000000</Unit_count>
    <Unit_count_type/>
  </Product>
  
</Products>
```

**csvsource.csv**

```
low;high;cost
0;1;20,5
1;2;20
2;3;21
3;4;22
4;5;23
5;6;23,5
6;7;24,5
7;8;25
8;9;26
9;10;27
```

Note that the CSV has been slightly modified but remains virtually identical in all important respects and the XML has been streamlined to remove elements that play no part in the following process and only serve to add `clutter` to the demo.

The PHP code will load the XML file and then find all `Product` elements within. For each `Product` we are interested in only two items - ( the weight and the price ) so we scan every line in the CSV file to compare the weight value in the XML to the low/high values in the csv - if the weight falls between these two values we use the cost associated to populate the XML price node.

```
# these are saved in same directory as test script - adjust to suit own environment & names.
$xmlfile='xmlsource.xml';
$csvfile='csvsource.csv';

# create DOMDocument & XPath objects
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $xmlfile );
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

# create CSV Parser & set the delimiter to semi-colon
$csv=new SplFileObject( $csvfile );
$csv->setFlags( SplFileObject::READ_CSV );
$csv->setCsvControl(';');


# Find all Product nodes & iterate through each
$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('Product');
foreach( $col as $node ){
    
    # Find the nodes of interest per product - weight & price
    $weight=floatval( $xp->query('DisplayWeight',$node)->item(0)->nodeValue );
    $price=$xp->query('shipping_price_vat_inc',$node)->item(0);
    
    
    # process each row in the CSV file to find items in the XML whose 
    # weight falls between the values low,high in the CSV file.
    foreach( $csv as $i => $row ){
        if( $i > 0 ){
            
            list( $low, $high, $cost )=$row;
            
            if( $weight > floatval( $low ) && $weight < floatval( $high ) ) {
                $price->nodeValue=strval( $cost );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
$dom->save($xmlfile);
```

The resultant XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <sku>35</sku>
    <sku_manufacturer>FIN 260182300000</sku_manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Finder</manufacturer>
    <ean>8012823238074</ean>
    <product_price_vat_inc>10.08</product_price_vat_inc>
    <quantity>3233</quantity>
    <!-- weight & price -->
    <shipping_price_vat_inc>20,5</shipping_price_vat_inc><!-- UPDATED -->
    <DisplayWeight>0.050000</DisplayWeight>
    <!-- -->
    <Unit_count>-1.000000</Unit_count>
    <Unit_count_type/>
  </Product>
  
  <Product>
    <sku>36</sku>
    <sku_manufacturer>FIN 260752300870</sku_manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Finder</manufacturer>
    <ean>803453238074</ean>
    <product_price_vat_inc>13.68</product_price_vat_inc><!-- UPDATED -->
    <quantity>7833</quantity>
    <!-- weight & price -->
    <shipping_price_vat_inc>23,5</shipping_price_vat_inc>
    <DisplayWeight>5.0850000</DisplayWeight>
    <!-- -->
    <Unit_count>-1.000000</Unit_count>
    <Unit_count_type/>
  </Product>
  
  <Product>
    <sku>37</sku>
    <sku_manufacturer>FIN 2601978970000</sku_manufacturer>
    <manufacturer>Finder</manufacturer>
    <ean>80128234674374</ean>
    <product_price_vat_inc>199.44</product_price_vat_inc>
    <quantity>32543</quantity>
    <!-- weight & price -->
    <shipping_price_vat_inc>24,5</shipping_price_vat_inc><!-- UPDATED -->
    <DisplayWeight>6.0650000</DisplayWeight>
    <!-- -->
    <Unit_count>-1.000000</Unit_count>
    <Unit_count_type/>
  </Product>
  
</Products>
```

Comment: Thank You ! But i have two problems:

1 at the part of function list(), i get undefined variables  Undefined array key 1 and  Undefined array key 2
2 i have impression that script take so long time for doing that, is taht normal?

Comment: I can make no comment about the time taken as, for me with such a small sample of data, it worked very fast. The error suggests that not every row in the csv file has 3 columns - again I can make no comment as the data given does not cause this error.

Comment: it s strange because every row has 3 columns (the file containt 1057 rows). That could be a problem of the loop ? because i have the impression that he find all rows for the 3 columns but it continue the loop until he fall in error because he not find key 1 and key 2

Comment: any blank lines at the end of the csv file?

Comment: no bnlank lines in csv

Comment: well I can't debug as I don't have the files. The above works fine for the given data shown here. With all the data it should be easier to identify the problem areas...